# UIWebView not loading in iOS 10

Tags: swift, swift3, uiwebview, ios10, ios10.3

After updating to iOS 10 and Swift 3 my webViews are not working. In the debug area is the following. It happens on device or in the simulator. Does anyone know what is causing this.

```
2017-05-23 20:04:19.453057-0500 AppName[394:32639] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
2017-05-23 20:04:19.453481-0500 AppName[394:32639] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
```

Comment: Could be to do with the ATS. Are you trying to access HTTP or HTTPS sites?

Comment: HTTP. It worked before iOS 10 and or Swift 3

Comment: If you are connecting to a HTTP website you have to either use SFSafariViewController or change your ATS settings.

Comment: Yes I have already set allow arbitrary loads to yes

Comment: show me your ViewController code

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem when I try to play a vimeo video in a UIWebView in IOS 10. In my case I was setting the HTML of the UIWebView in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

```
        let htmlString:String! = "<iframe src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/7100569\" width=\"\(self.view.frame.width - 20)\" height=\"\(self.videoWebView.frame.height)\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>"
        self.videoWebView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```

I solved the problem by putting this code in the `viewDidLoad()`

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to update this. Well turns out the client converted to a Linux server and didn't think it would matter so never mentioned it. The folder where the files were located contained capitals but the code in the app did not. When using a Linux server if the files or folders contain capitals then the URL must as well. Quick fix I just moved the files to a new folder without capitals.